# Udev Rule to discern 2 identical webcams on Linux

Tags: linux, udev, video

I have 2 identical webcams plugged into my Raspberry Pi. I want discern which camera is which based on the USB port they are plugged in to.

This is the purpose of udev, so I wrote the following rule:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", KERNEL=="1-1.3", ATTR{idVendor}=="05a3", ATTR{idProduct}=="9422", SYMLINK+="klastle/vlvid"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", KERNEL=="1-1.5", ATTR{idVendor}=="05a3", ATTR{idProduct}=="9422", SYMLINK+="klastle/irvid"
```

Which on a reboot shows these devices:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# ls -rlt /dev/klastle/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Feb 18 01:24 irvid -> ../bus/usb/001/007
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Feb 18 01:24 vlvid -> ../bus/usb/001/005
```

The problem is that these are not video for linux ( V4L2 ) devices and my application cannot open them.

How can I write my rule correctly to symlink the actual /dev/video0 and /dev/video1 to /dev/klastle/irvid and /dev/klastle/vlvid?

Thanks.

UPDATE: Here is the udevadm query output for both devices:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/video3
P: /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/video4linux/video3
N: video3
S: v4l/by-id/usb-Sonix_Technology_Co.__Ltd._USB_2.0_Camera_SN0001-video-index1
S: v4l/by-path/platform-3f980000.usb-usb-0:1.5:1.0-video-index1
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/v4l/by-path/platform-3f980000.usb-usb-0:1.5:1.0-video-index1 /dev/v4l/by-id/usb-Sonix_Technology_Co.__Ltd._USB_2.0_Camera_SN0001-video-index1
E: DEVNAME=/dev/video3
E: DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/video4linux/video3
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_FOR_SEAT=video4linux-platform-3f980000_usb-usb-0_1_5_1_0
E: ID_MODEL=USB_2.0_Camera
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=USB\x202.0\x20Camera
E: ID_MODEL_ID=9422
E: ID_PATH=platform-3f980000.usb-usb-0:1.5:1.0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=platform-3f980000_usb-usb-0_1_5_1_0
E: ID_REVISION=0100
E: ID_SERIAL=Sonix_Technology_Co.__Ltd._USB_2.0_Camera_SN0001
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=SN0001
E: ID_TYPE=video
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=uvcvideo
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:0e0100:0e0200:010100:010200:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
E: ID_V4L_CAPABILITIES=:capture:
E: ID_V4L_PRODUCT=USB 2.0 Camera: H264 USB Camera
E: ID_V4L_VERSION=2
E: ID_VENDOR=Sonix_Technology_Co.__Ltd.
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=Sonix\x20Technology\x20Co.\x2c\x20Ltd.
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=05a3
E: MAJOR=81
E: MINOR=3
E: SUBSYSTEM=video4linux
E: TAGS=:uaccess:seat:
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=3298533

root@raspberrypi:~# udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/video0
P: /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/video4linux/video0
N: video0
S: v4l/by-id/usb-Sonix_Technology_Co.__Ltd._USB_2.0_Camera_SN0001-video-index0
S: v4l/by-path/platform-3f980000.usb-usb-0:1.3:1.0-video-index0
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/v4l/by-path/platform-3f980000.usb-usb-0:1.3:1.0-video-index0 /dev/v4l/by-id/usb-Sonix_Technology_Co.__Ltd._USB_2.0_Camera_SN0001-video-index0
E: DEVNAME=/dev/video0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/video4linux/video0
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_FOR_SEAT=video4linux-platform-3f980000_usb-usb-0_1_3_1_0
E: ID_MODEL=USB_2.0_Camera
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=USB\x202.0\x20Camera
E: ID_MODEL_ID=9422
E: ID_PATH=platform-3f980000.usb-usb-0:1.3:1.0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=platform-3f980000_usb-usb-0_1_3_1_0
E: ID_REVISION=0100
E: ID_SERIAL=Sonix_Technology_Co.__Ltd._USB_2.0_Camera_SN0001
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=SN0001
E: ID_TYPE=video
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=uvcvideo
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:0e0100:0e0200:010100:010200:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
E: ID_V4L_CAPABILITIES=:capture:
E: ID_V4L_PRODUCT=USB 2.0 Camera: H264 USB Camera
E: ID_V4L_VERSION=2
E: ID_VENDOR=Sonix_Technology_Co.__Ltd.
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=Sonix\x20Technology\x20Co.\x2c\x20Ltd.
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=05a3
E: MAJOR=81
E: MINOR=0
E: SUBSYSTEM=video4linux
E: TAGS=:seat:uaccess:
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=3289947
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of `udevinfo -a` or `udevadm info -a` against the appropriate device or sysfs entry?

Comment: try https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/533464/202850 for how I did this a while back after much head scratching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rules are matching at the wrong level in the device tree: `SUBSYSTEM=="usb"` says you want a symlink to something that represents the complete USB device, and not the video4linux layer. So you need `SUBSYSTEM=video4linux`. You also need `ATTRS` and `KERNELS` (with extra S) instead of `ATTR` and `KERNEL`, because you want to much *those* further up in the tree. See `man udev` for details.

The way to get this information is to get `udevadm` to spit out the whole path up to the root of tree with attributes etc., with something like

```
udevadm info -a -p  $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/video3)
```

(you already did the inner part for the edit of your question).

So the rule should become something like

```
SUBSYSTEM=="video4linux", KERNELS=="1-1.3", ATTRS{idVendor}=="05a3", ATTRS{idProduct}=="9422", SYMLINK+="klastle/vlvid"
```

or similar, possibly depending on what you see in the device path.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. 4 identical cameras without serial numbers. On reboot there was a random reallocation. I needed to caption the pics, so this did not work.

The solution involves udev rules and some python code. You address the cameras as mycam1..4 instead of video0..3.  So mycam1 is always the same camera regardless of what videox number it has been allocated on boot.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/533464/202850

Comment: "Too long to post here." How to make people on the internet hate you 101.
I'm also unsure why you'd need python code; since - as the other answer also demonstrates - a single udev rule per device should be enough.