# Bind serial device address to specific usb port

Tags: udev, raspbian, usb-device

My OS: Raspbian Stretch Lite

**tl;dr;**

1. I have 2 identical USB device
2. I want to make sure their address didn't get confused
3. My thinking goes to bind the address to specific USB Port. I'm fine to "sacrifice" the port
4. Since I'm new on linux, I don't know how to do it. As far as my knowledge goes, udev differentiate device by it's ID, not port (different manufacturer, models, etc)
5. Is there any other recommended method?

**Long version:**
So, I have this UART-to-USB converter with the same manufacturer, so it have the same ID in udev and all. I want to make sure that the 2 device didn't get confused. For example, /dev/ttyUSB0 will always point to the specific hardware that I wanted (e.g.: inside. The 2 device will be separated by a door, so it's really important not to mess which is outside and inside).

I don't know how to accomplish this. My thinking goes to bind the specific port so that when the device is plugged to those specific port, it'll always give the address ttyUSB0 to that device. Is it even possible to do that? I'm new to linux and I know there's udev rule. But as far as I can find, it only bind device by it's id, not port. Or is there any other recommended way to do it using udev?

Here's my `udevadm` for the device:

```
  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0':
    KERNEL=="ttyUSB0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="tty"
    DRIVER==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/ttyUSB0':
    KERNELS=="ttyUSB0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial"
    DRIVERS=="cp210x"
    ATTRS{port_number}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0':
    KERNELS=="3-2:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="cp210x"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="02"
    ATTRS{interface}=="CP2102 USB to UART Bridge Controller"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2':
    KERNELS=="3-2"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="100mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0100"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="57"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="2"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="ea60"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="10c4"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Silicon Labs"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{product}=="CP2102 USB to UART Bridge Controller"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="removable"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0001"
    ATTRS{speed}=="12"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="1909"
    ATTRS{version}==" 1.10"
```

Note: If binding a port to a specific serial address means I can't use the port for any other device, then it's fine to me

Comment: Have a look at `/dev/serial/by-id/` and `/dev/serial/by-path/`.  Use those entries instead of `/dev/ttyUSB0`

Comment: @StephenHarris Ahhh, thank you dear sir! Care to add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @StephenHarris Quick question thought, will it randomly re-assign the port when I restart? For example, the "inside" is on port0, but after restart, it is assigned port1

Comment: I tend to use the `by-id` entries because that doesn't matter what port the device is plugged into.

Comment: @StephenHarris Thanks! So it means by-path is what I needed (I need the specific port)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than trying to make `udev` fix pathnames based on path, you may be able to directly use the values stored in `/dev/serial/by-path` and `/dev/serial/by-id`

These are symlinks to the `ttyUSB` device and are updated whenever a device is discovered.

eg on my machine:

```
% ls -l /dev/serial/by-path/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Dec 12 19:23 pci-0000:00:1a.0-usb-0:1.5.1:1.0-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Dec 12 19:23 pci-0000:00:1a.0-usb-0:1.5.1:1.1-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Dec  9 10:56 pci-0000:00:1a.0-usb-0:1.5.2:1.0-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Dec 12 19:23 pci-0000:00:1a.0-usb-0:1.5.4:1.0-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Dec 12 19:23 pci-0000:00:1a.0-usb-0:1.5.4:1.1-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Dec 12 19:24 pci-0000:00:1a.0-usb-0:1.6:1.0-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB5

% ls -l /dev/serial/by-id/  
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Dec  9 10:56 usb-1a86_USB2.0-Ser_-if00-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Dec 12 19:24 usb-1a86_USB2.0-Serial-if00-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Dec 12 19:23 usb-utek_USB__-__Serial_Cable_FTVW64JR-if00-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Dec 12 19:23 usb-utek_USB__-__Serial_Cable_FTVW64JR-if01-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Dec 12 19:23 usb-utek_USB__-__Serial_Cable_FTWKU6FP-if00-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Dec 12 19:23 usb-utek_USB__-__Serial_Cable_FTWKU6FP-if01-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/533464/202850. I had four identical cameras with no serial nos and thjey needed to be nailed down. I did it by USB port