# Same device name for identical USB sound cards after every reboot

Tags: linux, udev, alsa

I want to build a streaming server using Debian 10, Darkice and Icecast that streams two live recorded channels.

The sound cards are two Behringer UCA202 always plugged into the same physical USB-ports of the machine. Let's say one is the upper USB-port and the other one is the lower USB-port.

When checking with *amixer -l* one of the sound cards is named CODEC and the other one is CODEC_1. You can enter that in the config file of Darkice for the corresponding channel and assign a mountpoint for Icecast there.

So for the moment we have the following configuration:

Card in upper USB -> name is CODEC -> Mountpoint stream1 in Icecast

Card in lower USB -> name is CODEC_1 -> Mountpoint stream2 in Icecast

The problem is that after a reboot the sound cards can sometimes switch their names due to the nature of device discovery. CODEC becomes CODEC_1 and vice versa. And with this happening the streams on the mount points have also switched and stream1 is from the wrong sound card.

Now how can I assign the same name each time so that CODEC is always the sound card on the upper USB-port? Some kind of udev rule probably?

As requested I've added the output of udevadm info -ap /sys/

Here we go with the output of *udevadm info -ap /sys/class/sound/controlC0*

```
  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/sound/card0/controlC0':
    KERNEL=="controlC0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="sound"
    DRIVER==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/sound/card0':
    KERNELS=="card0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="sound"
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{id}=="CODEC_1"
    ATTRS{number}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0':
    KERNELS=="3-2:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="snd-usb-audio"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="01"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="01"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb3/3-2':
    KERNELS=="3-2"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="8"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{rx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="2"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="100mA"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{tx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0100"
    ATTRS{product}=="USB Audio CODEC "
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{speed}=="12"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="08bb"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="2902"
    ATTRS{version}==" 1.10"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 4"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Burr-Brown from TI              "
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="1331512"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb3':
    KERNELS=="usb3"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:1a.1"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="89"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0001"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{busnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{interface_authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{rx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{speed}=="12"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{product}=="UHCI Host Controller"
    ATTRS{version}==" 1.10"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0419"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{tx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="2"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 4.19.0-5-amd64 uhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:1a.1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="uhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{ari_enabled}=="0"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="0"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x2835"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x2808"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-1"
    ATTRS{irq}=="21"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x103c"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0300"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"
    ATTRS{revision}=="0x02"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="3"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

And here is the output of *udevadm info -ap /sys/class/sound/controlC1*

```
  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/sound/card1/controlC1':
    KERNEL=="controlC1"
    SUBSYSTEM=="sound"
    DRIVER==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/sound/card1':
    KERNELS=="card1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="sound"
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{id}=="CODEC"
    ATTRS{number}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0':
    KERNELS=="3-1:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="snd-usb-audio"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="01"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="01"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb3/3-1':
    KERNELS=="3-1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{tx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="8"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{speed}=="12"
    ATTRS{product}=="USB Audio CODEC "
    ATTRS{version}==" 1.10"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0100"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="5"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Burr-Brown from TI              "
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{rx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="100mA"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 4"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="62"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="2902"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="08bb"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb3':
    KERNELS=="usb3"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 4.19.0-5-amd64 uhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{interface_authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{product}=="UHCI Host Controller"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{rx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="2"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0419"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:1a.1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0001"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{speed}=="12"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="89"
    ATTRS{version}==" 1.10"
    ATTRS{tx_lanes}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:1a.1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="uhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-1"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{irq}=="21"
    ATTRS{revision}=="0x02"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0300"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x103c"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x2808"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="0"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="3"
    ATTRS{ari_enabled}=="0"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x2835"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

Comment: Some equivalent to the predictable network interface names? Not sure. But do those cards have a unique ID you can read from a startup script that adapts the config file?

Comment: `udevadm info -ap /sys/...` can be your friend to figure out the unique parameters. I think you might be able to use e.g. `ATTRS{devpath}` and/or `ATTRS{busnum}` to identify the devices by the usb socket they were plugged into. See http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html for how to write the rules..

Comment: @Whiskydrinker, Do you need more detailed assistance how to get going? Could you start with adding the output from `for i in /sys/class/sound/card* ; do udevadm info -ap $i ; done` into your question to get going?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the udevadm info supplied, you should be able to temporarily rename the 2 device IDs with:

```
echo 'CODEC_A' | sudo tee /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/sound/card1/id 

echo 'CODEC_B' | sudo tee /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/sound/card0/id
```

new alias id names should be shown in

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
```

for the udev rules, substitute 'card0' or 'card1' with 'card?' so card ID assigned by udev ignores card index number and is only based on USB connection

> DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/sound/card?",
> ATTR{id}="CODEC_A"
>
> DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/sound/card?",
> ATTR{id}="CODEC_B"

more information about this at https://alsa.opensrc.org/Udev

Comment: This has worked. But I had to add some additional wildcards since the 3 in usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0 sometimes became a 2 and sometimes a 4 when rebooting.

Comment: expect if there are more usb devices than just those 2 that they could boot to any order. posting your modified udev rules to show the additional wildcards would help other users if they need similar modifications

Comment: DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb?/?-2/?-2:1.0/sound/card?", ATTR{id}="CODEC_B" works for CODEC_B.

Comment: I had to adjust the wildcard from @Whiskydrinker to `?*`, i.e. `DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb?*/?*-2/?*-2:1.0/sound/card?", ATTR{id}="CODEC_B"` to account for cases when the assigned bus at boot is more than a single digit.

Answer (score 0):

My answer to

[Udev rules for seemingly indistinguishable devices](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/533464/330038)

might be helpful. I had 4 identical cameras to nail down ...